# Substituto para "bom dia/tarde/noite" no início de e-mails formais?

Tags: email, cumprimentos

Às vezes preciso enviar um e-mail formal (como um destinado à alguma empresa para fins profissionais), mas para não começar a falar direto, coloco "bom dia/tarde/noite". Porém isso não é o melhor a se dizer, pois o destinatário pode muito bem estar lendo em outro período do dia, como quando o e-mail fala "bom dia" mas o destinatário lê de noite, e automaticamente faz com que o mesmo cheque a hora de envio, que às vezes pode não ser do agrado do remetente.

Há algum substituto formal para essa saudação?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para e-mails formais, eu não aconselharia usar saudações do tipo "bom dia/tarde/noite".  Existem tantas outras introduções realmente formais como **"Prezado Sr/Sra...", "Sr/Sra...", "Dr....", "Meritíssimo", "Caro Sr/Sra..."**

Finalizando a correspondência, também formal, usa-se **"atenciosamente", "cordialmente", "respeitosamente"**, etc.

Comment: E no caso de e-mails profissionais à empresas?

Comment: @BrunoLopes   Para empresas, no Brasil, usamos apenas "Sr Gomes", "Sra Emília Flores"  , e quando não sabemos o nome, "Senhores"  ou "Prezado Senhor".

Comment: Ah, não sei. Eu estou procurando um cumprimento tão geral quanto bom dia/tarde/noite. Dizer "Prezado", "Sr/Sra", é um pouco incerto porque praticamente nunca sei o nome do responsável ou se é homem ou mulher. Além de que se referir diretamente ao responsável é meio oficial demais, como quando a intenção é fazer uma proposta ou acordo com uma empresa.

Comment: @BrunoLopes   No seu caso eu endereçaria "Sr. Gerente Comercial", "Sr Gerente de Contas", "Ao Diretor Comercial".  É o que se usa.  Você nunca recebeu uma carta endereçada "Ao morador do apt. 201" ou simplesmente "Ao morador"?

Comment: Também se aplica quando, por exemplo, o e-mail é para se candidatar a uma vaga?

Comment: @BrunoLopes   Porque não?   "Sr Gerente Geral de Recursos Humanos"  (procure informar-se a respeito de pelo menos o título de quem receberá sua correspondência.   Veja mais em http://modelodecartas.com.br/carta-comercial  e  também   http://brasilescola.uol.com.br/redacao/carta-comercial.htm

Answer (score 2):

Não vejo problemas em dar bom dia, boa tarde ou boa noite, afinal de contas você está desejando isso à pessoa, e não é a leitura que vai fazê-la ter o dia, tarde ou noite boa, e sim o seu desejo (isso analisando do ponto de vista do desejo).

Outro ponto é que a saudação referente ao turno reforça o momento em que o e-mail foi enviado, criando uma "pressão" para que seja respondido.

Bom, em relação a substitutos eu começaria com um "Prezado ...", ou "Caro ...". Pode usar também apenas um "Olá ..." ou ainda um "Oi ...".

Comment: Eu concordo com isso.

Answer (score 1):

Achei umas dicas aqui: http://licoespraticas.blogspot.com/2011/11/carta-formal-e-familiar-formulas-de.html

Neste caso, acho que poderia ser um destes: 
"Atenciosamente"
ou 
"Muito atentamente"